# How to add a reference and how to test if is it palindrom using unit test

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Firstly I have problem with Visual Studio I cann't add a reference. It says unable to add a reference to project ...

My second question is the testing, i'm not to testing, so could I know the difference between unit test and xunit test, I've seen a xunit is a NuGet package. And I'm not sure If I'm testing right if it's a palindrome.

I've tried to set my Framework to 4.0 I've seen it on SO, so I can add a reference but it didn't work.

```
namespace PalindromeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void IsItPalindrom()
        {
            string a = "1221";
            string b = "1221";
            string res = "";
            if (a == b)
            {
                  res =a;
                  bool x = Program.IsItPalindrom(res);
            }



            Assert.IsTrue(x);
        }
    }
}
```

My method for testing if the word is palindrome:

```
 private static bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = text.Length - 1;

            while (true)
            {
                if (min > max)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                char a = text[min];
                char b = text[max];

                if (char.ToLower(a) != char.ToLower(b))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                min++;
                max--;
            }
```

When I run the test or all the test I should see tick on the test explorer, but since I can't add a reference it says that program doesnt contain a definition for IsItPalindrom.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try to add the reference? Is it just "unable to add a reference to project"? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Only that, I'm using VS 2017

Comment: Are your test project (PalindromeTest) and your project in the same solution? Edit: just saw it, your method IsPalindrom will never be found outside of its class, as it is private. You would need to make it public to be able to call it from your unit test.

Comment: Yes, 1st project is called PalindromeChecker it's a WPF program and 2nd PalindromeTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Universal test project cannot reference a .NET Framework assembly. When you create the test project you should choose the `Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)` template under Visual C#->Test provided tghat your WPF application or class library targets the .NET Framework.

And xUnit has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Although xUnit has nothing to do with it, if John doe wants to know about the different unit testing frameworks, here is a good blog post to start informing yourself about the three most common ones: [link](https://raygun.com/blog/unit-testing-frameworks-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Your projects are incompatible with each other. If your main project's target is netcoreapp -> than your test projects should be netcoreapp.

If your main project's target is netframework -> than your test projects should be netframework too.

But you can add a reference to netstandard library from any of .NET Frameworks

Comment: I think, shouldn't. How can you test "private static" method from another project? It should be public to make invocation available

Comment: I don't get it? :D

Comment: xUnit has nothing to do with this. You seem to be using MSTest. What kind of projects did you create?

Comment: 1st WPF and this is the 2nd PalindromeTest

Comment: @M.Artem I did same problem as before

Comment: Can you give us a bit of source code? Maybe somewhere like GitHub?
two .csproj files would be enough.

Comment: In what kind of project is the `IsPalindrome` method defined? It should be a class libary that targets the same version of the .NET Framework as the test project does.

Comment: Here is the link, I don't use github [link]https://www.sendspace.com/file/jt6gop , that's my full prgm

Comment: @JohnDoe: Is that a `WPF User Control Library` or what project template did you use? And what template did you use to create the test project?

Comment: @mm8 I used WPF App(.Net Framework), and for the test project Unit Test App ( Universal Windows), you can take look at my file if you want .

Comment: A Universal Windows test project cannot reference a .NET Framework assembly.

Comment: You should use the UnitTest Project (.Net Framework) template in this case.